# Тире, двоеточие или запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, двоеточие, тире-или-двоеточие

Как правильно расставить знаки препинания: *Цена товара от 70 до 120 рублей*; *От зерен до вашей чашки увлекательная история кофе*; *От одежды на вас до телефона у вас в руках любая вещь требует работы дизайнера*?